# Why does apt-get clean requires a reboot before taking effect

Tags: apt, disk-usage

Sometimes when my disk is full I `apt-get clean` to free up some space. When I check my free space with `df` I have no space left, but after a reboot `df` tells me disk is being used for 52%. Why do I need to reboot before it the clean operating takes effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reboot you do only flushes the file system buffer. You can manually clean the file system buffer by running `sync`.

[man sync](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sync.1.html):

> sync, syncfs - commit buffer cache to disk

So after you do `sudo apt-get clean` do `sync` and then run `df` to get the updated values.

Related:

- [How do you empty the buffers and cache on a Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I just noticed on an different machine that `apt-get clean` worked without `sync`. Why is that?

Comment: I tried to check if `sync` was being run as a cron job, but it seems like it isn't. Can you double check your claim and whether clean surely cleared/deleted packages?